# Team not appearing in Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I accepted an invitation to join a team on iTunes Connect. My role allows me to upload builds. The problem is the team does not appear in Xcode. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out that to be able to upload builds for a team you need two invitations. One from the Member Center where you should have the Admin role. The other one from iTunes Connect where you need also to have the Admin role (actually the Developer role would be enough but its not working at the time of this answer).

The role from Member Center gives you the technical means to create the right build (like provisioning profiles). The role from iTunes Connect is about being able to upload this build for the right team.